# Do charged particles in Uniform Rectilinear Motion also give rise to magnetic fields in respect to stationary references?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, waves

From Wiki, I already know that EM waves are generated whenever charged particles are accelerated. Also, accelerated charges (as in electric current) give rise to magnetic fields near them. My question is, if this charged particle IS MOVING in respect to a stationary person, but not accelerated under any force, thus basically in uniform rectilinear motion (resultant force equal to zero) do they still give rise to a magnetic field in respect to said stationary observer?

I think its a simple enough question. English is not my first language so sorry for any weirdly constructed sentences.

Comment: A moving charge is a current...

Comment: So the answer is yes I guess? I though a current had to necessarily be created when an Electric Field accelerates charged particles, thus not configuring uniform motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentials for arbitrary motion of a test particle have been studied, and they answer to the name of Liénard-Wiechert potentials. Basically, what they did was to take the Maxwell equations and solve them for a distribution that was corresponding to a point charge.

You can find more on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential, or on any textbook on electromagnetism (they usually are calculated after introducing relativity). I refer to the Wikipedia page for the formulas under "Definition of Liénard–Wiechert potentials". They are what you are looking for: there the potentials are calculated for a particle in arbitrary position $\vec r_s$ and with arbitrary, constant velocity $\vec \beta_s$. Look out that you have to evaluate at retarded time, that takes relativistic effects into account! It is defined as (it is not in that section of Wikpiedia)
$$
t_r=t-\frac{|\vec r-\vec r_s|}{c},
$$
where $\vec r$ is the position in which you are evaluating.

You see that the vector potential has a leading order that is proportional to velocity. That means that, when velocity goes to zero, the vector potential vanishes, and you recover the electrostatic potential.

Comment: Cool, I’ll read it carefully. Complex math, however, isn’t my strength. How would you answer it in layman’s terms regarding the presence of a magnetic field in linear motion charges?

Comment: Well, an intuition has already been given in the comment by Rob Jeffries. A moving particle is a current, so there is magnetic field. But there's something even funnier: if you are watching a non moving charge, you see the electrostatic field. If you start running at constant velocity, you see a current, and the magnetic field appears. This is an example on a fact that is evident in relativity: electric and magnetic fields are not independent of each other, and they transform into each other when changing frame of reference (aka getting a Lorentz boost).

Comment: (An hint for reading that could be useful at your level: $\vec A$ is related to the magnetic field (and a bit to the electric field), $\varphi$ is related to the electric field. If $\vec A$ is zero, then the magnetic field is zero (the correspondent with $\varphi$ does not hold, but let's ignore that). So, as $\vec A$ vanishes as the velocity $\beta$ goes to zero, the magnetic field also vanishes.)

Comment: Thanks for the math interpretation as well, will read carefully

Comment: Roberto, a more subtile view shows that electrons obeying a magnetic dipole moment which is randomly distributed. For moving electrons (in currents) their magnetic dipole moments get aligned and this is the magnetic field one observe around current carrying wires.

Comment: HolgerFiedler, thanks for the answer but could you expand on it a little? I don’t think I quite understand. Does that mean the electrons have magnetic fields even when stationary due to spin? Is that it?